# Mongoose: como hacer find con populate

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para realizar una consulta a la bd trayendo todos los resultados que cumplan con el campo 'store' {name}, pero este 'store' esta guardado con '_id' y uso .populate() para que me traiga la info

```
const products = await Product.find({ 'store.name' : "Ejemplo1" })
                .populate('store', 'name')
```

los esquemas son los siguientes:

```
const storeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:"lo agrega mongoose de manera auto",
  name: String
})
export default model('Store', storeSchema);

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  store: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Store"
  }
})
```

basicamente lo que quiero lograr es extraer de la BD  todos los productos con 'store' especifico, pero aun no logro hacerlo, les agradezco cualquier ayuda para solventar esto, asi sea una referencia o un ejemplo de un query adecuado, gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es un `aggregate`, el `.populate()` es úna consulta extra que se hace después de la consulta inicial... es decir, no puedes hacer una consulta basado en el resultado de populate. Entonces tienes 2 opciones, hacer un aggregate usando $lookup, o hacer 2 consultas, una para consultar cual es el store con ese name... y sacas el id y buscas los productos de ese store.

Comment: hice uso de lookup junto a aggregate y funciona de lo mejor, gracias por tomarte un tiempo en responder esta pregunta